# Background rollover on a horizontal navigation with vertical dividers

Tags: html, css, background, navigation

I have a navigation that is built in a way:

```
<ul class='mainnav'>
<li><a href="#"> Link 1 </a></li>
<li><a href="#"> Link 2 </a></li>
<li><a href="#"> Link 3 </a></li>
</ul>
```

and I have a small border on the right of each of the items. The border is not going all the way from top to bottom, so I have put it on the `<a>` tag instead of `<li>`

Now, in the '`selected`' state of my navigation I want the `<li>`'s background to change to a different color, but I run into 2 problems:

1. my `<li>` and my `<a>` are not the same width.
2. in Chrome, it changes the background in `<a>` despite my good
   intentions.

Here's my css. I would appreciate if someone knows how to do this, has been fighting for days...

```
#navigation{background-color:#294964; width:100%; height:40px; display:block;}
#navigation ul.mainnav{height:35px; display:block; margin:0; }
#navigation ul.mainnav li{display:inline; cursor: pointer; height: 40px;  line-height:40px;margin:0px; padding:12px 0;}
#navigation ul.mainnav li a{ border-right: 1px solid #49647B; color: #FFFFFF;  padding:     4px 15px; text-decoration: none; width:100%; font-size: 14px; }
#navigation ul.mainnav li a:hover{ color: #a4a47e;}
#navigation ul.mainnav li.selected {background-color:#0b1b32;}
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` in an "inline" element, give is `display:block` so width, margin, padding etc can be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Use block or inline-block for the display of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to actually refrain from setting any dimensions for your `<li>` elements, and instead apply all of those within your `<a>` tag. That way, the entire part of the navigation element will be clickable, and will change on hover.

HTML:

```
<ul class='mainnav'>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li class="selected"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.mainnav { 
    background-color: #294964; 
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 40px; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: block; }
.mainnav li { 
    float: left;
    margin: 0; }
.mainnav li a { 
    color: #fff;  
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 29px; /* 40 - 11 */
    padding: 11px 15px 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #49647B;
    display: block; }
.mainnav li:first-child a { border-left: 0; }
.mainnav li a:hover, .mainnav li.selected a {
    background-color: #0b1b32;
    color: #a4a47e; }
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/NR9az/